# How to make a discord bot that has access to all the messages that come to my account

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have the following problem, I just created a bot that reads the messages of a specific channel and then I can use them, but I can only invite the bot to my own servers

1. Is there a way to copy the messages from a server and send them to where I am the administrator?
2. or to invite a bot to a server without being the administrator?
3. or make a bot that can read my own messages (since I am inside the discord)

I have been trying all this with discordjs and nodejs but I have not had good results, I can do it perfectly on my own server but when it is an external server I do not know how to do it, if someone knows please help <3

Comment: you seem to figure it out? Could you share your solution?

Comment: If I solved it on my own a while ago, to be able to access your account you will need a previous version of discord, in the current one it is impossible (or at least I have no idea how to do it) if you use the version

   "discord.js": "^ 11.4.2",

You can use your account as if it were a normal bot, you can google how to have your personal token ;D you're welcome, this info would have served me a few months ago

Answer (score 0):

1. Technically, yes.
2. To invite a bot, you must have the "Manage Server" permission.
3. [Discord's OAuth2 implementation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) can allow you to fetch messages from a channel the user has access to.

I'm not going to provide any code, examples, or further information as this seems like you're trying to invade other user's privacy, which will most likely get you banned from Discord.

Comment: They are the messages that reach my account ... not anything private from other people. But I already did. It is not possible to put a bot to a discord where you are not an administrator, but it is not necessary to get the messages that reach my account